# How do I make the directories in a zip file relative to the target directory instead of my working directory

Tags: command-line, zip

I'm calling the zip command from a script where I cannot change directory.
I need to make a zip file of the stuff in `data/kit123/` from the directory which data resides in, but I want the contents of the zip to only be the contents of `kit123`, with paths relative to `kit123`.

This is the directory structure

```
myworkingdir
    data
        kit123
            kitpart1
                file.xcf
                anotherfile.xcf
            kitpart2
                ...
        kit124
            ...
```

My script runs in myworkingdir and cannot change directories.

If I call

```
zip -r kit123.zip data/kit123
```

then the structure in the zip file will be

```
data
    kit123
        kitpart1
            file.xcf
            anotherfile.xcf
        kitpart2
```

but I want it to be

```
kit123
    kitpart1
        file.xcf
        anotherfile.xcf
    kitpart2
```

Is there a zip option I can use to accomplish this? It seems odd that it should depend on my working directory

I know it's not -j. that one destroys the structure within kit123

Comment: Bah, nevermind I did figure out how to change dir (in Python) I just had a poorly organized permissions.

I'd still like to know if zip has such an option though.

Comment: Python `zipfile.write(arcname=` allows it btw: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As you note in the comments you now know how to change directory with your script, I'll explain the situation with zip regarding relative paths.

It is probably easiest to open terminal and `cd` to `kit123`; you have to make the target directory your working directory- you can't run the command from the base of your home directory or it will pick up all the paths of `/home/$USER/..` If you use the `-j` option, it will strip out all paths, as there isn't really an equivalent of the tar option `--strip` with which different levels of path removal can be specified.

So please cd to your target directory (`kit123`) and enter:

```
zip -r kit123.zip *
```

This will recursively (`-r`) preserve all (`*`) files and directories of files in the current directory (`kit123`), and as relative paths (`-p`) are preserved automatically unless the `-j` option is present, the directory structure will be as you wished. `Kit123` and subfolders (`kitpart1`) with their own files will be present:

```
kit123
    kitpart1
        file.xcf
        anotherfile.xcf
    kitpart2
```

You can check the contents of the zip file with `unzip -l zipfile.zip`.

For more information on the other options available for `zip`, see `man zip` and the [Ubuntu manpage online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/zip.1.html).

Comment: that would be cool - unless there are also `.*` files in  that directory. in such case `*` wildcard is not enough

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12493206/zip-including-hidden-files
TL;DR: should be `zip -r file.zip .`